# modsecurity whitelist directory

Tags: apache, mod-security, cwp

For me to whitelist a directory, is this how I should do it?

```
<Directory home/xxxxx/public_html/xxxx/source/api/>
    SecRuleEngine Off
</Directory>
```

.

> Edit: /usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/xxxxx/xxx.site.com/modsec.conf

```
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
    SecRuleEngine On
    SecRuleRemoveById 210381
    SecRuleRemoveById 211680
</IfModule>

<Directory home/xxxxx/public_html/xxx/source/api/>
    SecRuleEngine Off
</Directory>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the one way how to do it. Note that SecRuleEngine can be used also in .htaccess .